# wxImageList::Add() always returns 0

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wxwidgets

according to the [**manual**](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_image_list.html#a2022beccd2564ee2be79b273246b50a8), `wxImageList::Add()` should return the index position of a newly added image.

But in my application, I only get the return values `0` (when adding an image went OK) or `-1` (when it failed). When I debug into the function

```
int wxImageList::Add(const wxBitmap& bitmap, const wxColour& maskColour)
```

this seems to be clear for me: using Windows the returned values comes from a call to `ImageList_AddMasked()` / `IsolationAwareImageList_AddMasked()` / `__IsolationAware_pfn()` where the latter one does seem to return a `BOOL` but not an list index value.

**So my question is:** how can I get the index value of the recently added image?

Comment: What is `IsolationAwareImageList_AddMasked`? Isn't it just a wrapper around `ImageList_AddMasked`?

Comment: @David Heffernan no, as mentioned in my post, ImageList_AddMasked() calls IsolationAwareImageList_AddMasked() calls __IsolationAware_pfn()

Comment: Usually `/` would indicate alternatives. But I see what you mean. I find it a little hard to imagine that the documentation for `ImageList_AddMasked` is wrong in that way.

Comment: According to [this](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10013), you might be able to work around this via `GetImageCount` before inserting the image. I do however suspect that there is some other underlying issue here because MSDN is adamant that `ImageList_AddMasked` returns the index since at least 2005. Are you sure that your list isn't just always empty before insertion?

Comment: you mistake - `ImageList_AddMasked` is imported function from *comctl32.dll*, when `IsolationAwareImageList_AddMasked` is inline function inside your binary. this is `IsolationAwareImageList_AddMasked` call `ImageList_AddMasked` (activate activation context before this and deactivate after) but not visa versa. @DavidHeffernan is correct here

Comment: and anyway `ImageList_AddMasked` return correct added image index

Answer (score 0):

The obvious idea is to just use `wxImageList::GetImageCount()`, is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Given that there is no reason to doubt that `ImageList_AddMasked` works correctly, one can only assume that if `ImageList_AddMasked` returns zero then so will `GetImageCount`

Comment: and `ImageList_AddMasked == ImageList_GetImageCount - 2` (if no errors) which is not obvious

Comment: @RbMm Where do you get this result? At least under Windows 7, adding a single image, masked or not, only increases the count by 1.

Comment: my mistake - if we add bitmap with exactly size - size of bitmap equal to cx,cy args in `ImageList_Create` - added one image to list, but if use another bitmap size, added 2